# How do I add an entire directory to a QT creator project

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have an existing QT Creator project. I want to add an entire directory to this project. I see that I can right click in the project file browser tree and "Add Existing Files..." However through this dialog box, I can only add individual files. How can I include an entire directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way is to directly edit your .pro file, add `HEADERS += mydir/*.h` and `SOURCES += mydir/*.cpp` and the contents of the whole directory will show up in QT Creator. Further reference: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html

Comment: What if these aren't c++ files? Lets say they are just a bunch of .txt files that I want to edit inside QT Creator.

Comment: What if I use cmake instead of qmake?

Answer (score 11):

Open a terminal, navigate to the folder where you want to have you project file, and then run the command

```
qmake -project
```

This will search the current directory and all subdirectories for files with extensions such as `.c`, `.cpp`, `.h`, etc. (the full list is found by typing `man qmake`).

But keep in mind that it will overwrite your current .pro file if you already have a project set up.

Answer (score 3):

qmake provides a convenient [`files`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#files-pattern-recursive-false) function for this very purpose. Adding the following line to your project file will add `.cpp` files inside the `src/` directory:

```
SOURCES += $$files(src/*.cpp)
```

By default, this is non-recursive. Setting the second parameter to `true` recursively finds all files:

```
SOURCES += $$files(src/*.cpp, true)
```

The `files` function was introduced since [Qt 5.10](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qmake-function-reference.html#files-pattern-recursive-false).

Comment: This worked at least in Qt 5.15. Is "SOURCES += src/*.cpp" deprecated, since that did not work?

Comment: With `SOURCES += src/*.cpp`, QtCreator *does* show the files matching the wild-card, but when compiling, it emits an ominous warning: "*Failure to find: src/*.cpp*"...

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can just **right click on project name** and select `Add existing directory`