# Issue opening file with ifstream in qt

Tags: c++, qt, istream

my partner wrote a bunch of code for one of my projects in a text editor, when i run the code it works perfectly.....
now i have copy and pasted all the code into qt creator, and im having an issue

```
 stringstream ss;
            string line;
            ifstream myfile;
            myfile.open("Instructors.txt");
            if (myfile.is_open()){
                while (getline(myfile,line)){
                    ss << line << ", ";
                }
                myfile.close();
            }
            else cout << "bad open" << endl;
```

above is the part fo my code that is having the issue, i can assure you all Instructors.txt is indeed in in the correct file, but everytime our code reaches this point imstead of opening the file i get thrown to the else "bad open" why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say what it may be without any error code, what you can do is to improve your error message with something more meaningful (for you and for your customers):

```
else cout << "Error opening file: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
```

`strerror` (see [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strerror/)) function returns a string for a given error code captured in by `errno` macro.

Otherwise you can do it much more C++ish using exceptions: first enable them for your stream:

```
myfile.exceptions(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit);
```

Then catch them, all together is:

```
try
{
    ifstream myfile("Instructors.txt");
    myfile.exceptions(ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit);

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        ss << line << ", ";
    }

    myfile.close();
}
catch (ifstream::failure e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Comment: its gave me no such file or directory error, this is confusing me because i first tired to simply copy and paste the files into my workspace, but after that didn't work created new text files in qt the copy and pasted the contents over and it still didn't work

Comment: Well...then check you really have that file in the working directory of your executable...how to do it depends on your build/make system...

Comment: will the output between these 2 methods b different?

Comment: in qt, i rightclick on the working directory goto add new, then click on text file, this adds it to Other_Files, so i then tried to open "Other_Files/Instructors" this doesn't appear to work, but i find it impossible for it to not be in my working directory

Comment: @AndrewOtsuki Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051502/how-do-i-add-an-entire-directory-to-a-qt-creator-project)?

Comment: nope, but i already knew that a little background, im writing a client server program to evaluate teaching assistants, the clients i wrote in qt will connect to the server written in Gedit, i can compile the both of them and they run oh so smoothly, but trying to put the server onte QT there is some 'magical' problem lol

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite file name, may be it contains characters from different encodings.

Comment: my first comment for adrianos' post i tried this, wiht no luck unfortunatly

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

double check the working directory, chances are it is in the build folder (where the executable gets dropped)

in QtCreator you can fix this by going to projects and selecting run; there you will be able to set the working directory

Comment: I actually cant find the build folder for this one? all my other qt projects the build folder is right next to my workspace